# How to pass target parameter for UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I write one category method in `UIView+Extensions.m`:

```
@interface UIView (Extensions)
+ (UIView*)configureMoreViewWithBtns:(NSArray*)btnsConf;
@end

+ (UIView*)configureMoreViewWithBtns:(NSArray*)btnsConf
{
    UIView* moreView = [[self alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(195, 180, 120, 100)];
    [moreView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    for (int i = 0; i < btns.count; i++) {
        NSDictionary* confDict = btnsConf[i];

        UIButton* btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, i*30 + 10, 120, 20)];
        btn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
        [btn setTitle:confDict[@"title"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn addTarget:self 
                action:NSSelectorFromString(confDict[@"selector"] 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [moreView addSubView:btn];
    }
    return moreView;
}
```

But this implement is wrong, because i don't know how pass `target` parameter from my ViewController?

In my viewController, i called this method like this:

```
- (void)handleMoreImageTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    UITableViewCell* tappedCell = [UIView tableViewCellFromTapGestture:gestureRecognizer];

    NSArray* btnsConf = @[
        @{@"title": @"分享", @"selector": NSStringFromSelector(@selector(handleShare:))},
        @{@"title": @"私信", @"selector": NSStringFromSelector(@selector(handleSiXin:))},
        @{@"title": @"举报或屏蔽", @"selector": NSStringFromSelector(@selector(handleJuBao:))}
                         ];  
    UIView* moreView = [UIView configureMoreViewWithBtns:btnsConf];    
}
```

Comment: Add `self` to your `confDict` with the key `target` and set that as the target `[btn addTarget:confDict[@"target"] ....` or am I missing something?

Comment: @sbarow Could speak more detail? what's the value for key `target`?

Comment: maybe, you need to make some modification in the extension and add a new value for key `target`?

Comment: How can i modify `handleMoreImageTapped`? Could i write `@{@"target": self}`?

Comment: @BlackMamba see @hoiberg42 answer, that is what I meant by adding self. You create that dictionary from your `ViewController` adding `self` which is the `ViewController` to the dictionary and then passing that dictionary to the `UIView` extension.

Answer (score 2):

You need to also pass the target (the object the selector would be called on, in this case the viewcontroller from which you call the `configuremoreviewwithbtns` method) in the dictionairies.
So a dictionairy you add to the array would become

```
@{@"title": @"thetitle", @"selector": NSStringFromSelector(@selector(theselector:)), @"target": self},
```

and you'd have to change the UIView extension to this:

```
[btn addTarget:confDict[@"target"]
            action:NSSelectorFromString(confDict[@"selector"] 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```